# Dynamically generating a clocktable with variable ":block" parameter using ELisp

Tags: org-clock, org-clock-table

I want to create a source block with following header in an Org file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var start=2023-01-01 :var end=2023-01-31
```

When I execute this source block, I want it to create a following clocktable:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope tree :maxlevel 6 :indent nil :block 2023-01-01 :stepskip0 t :tcolumns 1 :level t :header "#+NAME: time-in-tasks\n"
```

Then process the data from that table, destroy it in some way (overriding with an updated data would be fine) and repeat the whole process, replacing `:block 2023-01-01` with `:block 2023-01-02`, `:block 2023-01-03`, etc. until `:block 2023-01-31`.

How can I create and update clocktable programmatically using ELisp?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: So creating it via the source block is essential? (maybe you could explain why) Thus creating the clocktable directly via `org-clock-report` and then shifting it using `org-clocktable-try-shift` is not a viable alternative?

Comment: Right now I need to do four actions to post my times for a day - update a timestamp at the top of the tree (for Timestamp column), update the timestamp in the clocktable header, update clocktable, then execute the source block. If I could set the start and end time as variables in source block, then I could do the same for any number of days with three actions.